# Java Max and Min Integer value error message output

Tags: java

I am working with Java and attempting to add a statement in this code that displays an error message, outside the:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: 

"31243241234123423"
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2123)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at MaxInteger.main(MaxInteger.java:22)
```

error message that Java provides. I am looking to add:

```
System.out.println("Your Integer value is out of range.");
```

This is the portion of the code that I am trying to add it to:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework1a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int intOne = 0;
        int intTwo = 0;
        String operation = " ";
        int result = 0;
        double divResult = 0.0;

        // Use the Scanner class to input data
        Scanner scannerIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Display of Program Introduction
        System.out.println("This program will take your integer inputs, " +
                            "along with the choosen operation and calculate the results");

        // Display for user to input the first integer
        System.out.println("Enter the first integer:");
            intOne = scannerIn.nextInt();

        // Display for user to input the second integer
        System.out.println("Enter the second integer:");
            intTwo = scannerIn.nextInt();

        // Display a list of instructions on the proper call for the operator
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("********** Operator Instructions **********");
        System.out.println("\t For addition use +");
        System.out.println("\t For subtraction use -"); 
        System.out.println("\t For multiplication use *");  
        System.out.println("\t For division use /");
        System.out.println("\t For modulus use %");
        System.out.println("\t For bitwise AND use &");
        System.out.println("\t For bitwise inclusive OR use |");
        System.out.println("********************************************");
        System.out.println("");

        // Takes care of the ENTER key negating the String input below
        scannerIn.nextLine();

        // Display for user to input the chosen operator
        System.out.println("Enter the operation:");
            operation = scannerIn.nextLine();
    }
}
```

The other instance I am trying to incorporate is when the addition, subtraction, multiplication result exceeds the max integer value display a similar prompt. Any suggestions or furthering questions?

Comment: Look into try/catch blocks.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Comment: @fox josh Take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework1a
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int intOne = 0;
        int intTwo = 0;
        String operation = " ";
        int result = 0;
        double divResult = 0.0;

        // Use the Scanner class to input data
        Scanner scannerIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Display of Program Introduction
        System.out.println("This program will take your integer inputs, "
                + "along with the choosen operation and calculate the results");

        try
        {
            // Display for user to input the first integer
            System.out.println("Enter the first integer:");
            intOne = scannerIn.nextInt();

            // Display for user to input the second integer
            System.out.println("Enter the second integer:");
            intTwo = scannerIn.nextInt();

            // Display a list of instructions on the proper call for the operator
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("********** Operator Instructions **********");
            System.out.println("\t For addition use +");
            System.out.println("\t For subtraction use -");
            System.out.println("\t For multiplication use *");
            System.out.println("\t For division use /");
            System.out.println("\t For modulus use %");
            System.out.println("\t For bitwise AND use &");
            System.out.println("\t For bitwise inclusive OR use |");
            System.out.println("********************************************");
            System.out.println("");

            // Takes care of the ENTER key negating the String input below
            scannerIn.nextLine();

            // Display for user to input the chosen operator
            System.out.println("Enter the operation:");
            operation = scannerIn.nextLine();
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Your Integer value is out of range.");
        }
    }
}
```

Read about [exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) to understand what this code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it.

- Using if
- Using try-catch

## First Approach

You may use an **if-statement** to check whether the input is larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. But you need to use a datatype of larger capacity, else it will throw you an **InputMismatchException** the moment you entered a value more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147483647).

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
Long num = 0L;
num = scn.nextLong();

if(num > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    System.out.println("Your Integer value is out of range.");
```

---

## Second Approach

The other approach is by using a **try-catch** block. This way there is no need to use a long datatype to check in input exceeding `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = 0;

try{
    num = scn.nextInt();
}
catch(InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("Your Integer value is out of range.");  
}
```

Personally I would prefer the second approach which is what **try-catch** blocks are meant for - to catch unexpected behaviour such as exceeding data range. Further more, using the second approach, the program will print `"Your integer value is out of range"` even if the user input an extremely large number (such as 99999999999999999999999999999999999). The first approach wouldn't be able to handle an input larger than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

---

## Program Testing (2nd approach)

```
Input: 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999

Your Integer value is out of range.
```